# Windows Phone 7 UI (Metro) possible on iOS?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uikit, ios

How hard would be be to recreate Windows Phone 7 UI animations on an iOS device using UIKit? 
More specifically, making animated boxes gradually move from side-to-side, and appear in a chained manner.

For example, windows phone 7 transitions here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUeNCzRhhDE
At 0:30 - the parallax scrolling effect (relatively easy?);
At 1:22 - the chained animation of the home screen;

Is this possible with CoreAnimation and UILayers, if so how complex would it get?
Thanks

Comment: Prepare for your app to be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: Did they ban WindowsPhone7Api*() calls too? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not incredibly hard. For some things like parallax scrolling you can just use some of the basic view animation code and set different timings for different elements to get the effect.

Look at the animations Apple has in the Apple stores for providing help (similar to some of their screen savers). These are similar to what Windows is doing.

The bigger question would be whether it improves the user experience or just makes them wait longer to be able to interact your application.

Comment: How would I go about making the door-open effect for a UIView, CALayer + CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation? If it is not incredibly hard, I believe more animation libraries would be visible. Seems strange. It increases UX considerably.

Comment: You don't need animation libraries because the built in view animation does a lot already, and if you need more CoreAnimation is incredibly powerful.  That's why you don't see any, they are built in!  Good animation does add to UX considerably, making use of it judiciously is the hallmark of a good app.

Comment: I'm on the wrong machine to verify it 100%, but I believe you may want something like CATransform3DRotate (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html)